# Using C Header in C++ Program

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, compilation, compiler-errors

I have a C header file which contains an enum

```
typedef enum {leaf, operator} my_type;
```

Now when I try to include this header in my C++ program I get error 
"expected identifier before ‘operator’"

How can I get rid of it.

Comment: Compilers usually specify a line number when they spit out an error. Unless you can supply the code at that line, people here are unlikely to be able to help.

Answer (score 7):

Operator is a reserved word in C++. Name that part of your `enum` something else.

Comment: There is no other way, actually this header is part of third party library on which I dont have any control.

Comment: That gets.. complicated. Is the library already built, or do you compile it yourself?

Comment: Maybe you can wrap this library in another C dll.

Comment: Yes, the library is already built ( i.e. static library) and also I am trying this on Linux Platform.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a dirty trick like this might work?

```
#define operator operator_
extern "C" {
    #include "library.h"
}
#undef operator
```

Make sure that `operator_` doesn't clash with anything in that header though.

Answer (score 1):

Even if it's a third party library, you should be able to just change the header. It's not likely to break anything if you compiled the library with a C compiler beforehand.

If you don't wanna do that, you can write a wrapper, compile that with a C compiler and use the wrapper from C++ instead of using the library directly. Annoying, but the only way I can think of right now that's definitely going to work.

I'm not sure if this would work, but I suppose you could also try something like

```
#define operator OPERATOR
#include <thelibrary>
#undef operator
```

Normally the preprocessor doesn't care too much about what you do with it, but I'm not sure if this'll work considering operator is a keyword.